# unable to solve "nvcc fatal: A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified" error

Tags: ros, nvidia, syntax, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to find if there is any problem with the below build command generated by catkin_make. Similar questions on forums say that there must be some problem with the syntax of the command generated by cmake. Could some one help me find it ?

My system arch is aarch64 (Nvidia TX1) and OS is ubuntu 16.04. The same code builds perfectly on my ubuntu PC.

```
 -- Generating dependency file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/build/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/CMakeFiles/KinfuLargeScaleCUDA.dir/kinfu_large_scale/src/cuda/KinfuLargeScaleCUDA_generated_colors.cu.o.NVCC-depend
Scanning dependencies of target KinfuLargeScaleCPP
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -M -D__CUDACC__ /home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/kinfu_large_scale/src/cuda/colors.cu -o /home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/build/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/CMakeFiles/KinfuLargeScaleCUDA.dir/kinfu_large_scale/src/cuda/KinfuLargeScaleCUDA_generated_colors.cu.o.NVCC-depend -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -m64 -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"kinfu\" -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DDISABLE_OPENNI2 -DDISABLE_PCAP -DDISABLE_PNG -DvtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths ) -DvtkIOExodus_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkIOParallelExodus ) -DvtkIOGeometry_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkIOMPIParallel ) -DvtkIOImage_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkIOMPIImage ) -DvtkIOSQL_AUTOINIT=2 ( vtkIOMySQL,vtkIOPostgreSQL ) -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkRenderingContextOpenGL ) -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=4 ( vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL,vtkRenderingOpenGL ) -DvtkRenderingFreeType_AUTOINIT=2 ( vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig,vtkRenderingMatplotlib ) -DvtkRenderingLIC_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkRenderingParallelLIC ) -DvtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL ) -DDISABLE_OPENNI2 -DKinfuLargeScaleCUDA_EXPORTS -Xcompiler ,\"-fPIC\",\"-g\" -D_FORCE_INLINES -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 --ftz=true --prec-div=false --prec-sqrt=false -DNVCC -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include -I/usr/include/vtk-6.2 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/jsoncpp -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/freetype2 -I/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/tcl -I/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/containers/include -I/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/utils/include -I/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/kinfu_large_scale/include -I/home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/src/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/kinfu_large_scale/src -I/usr/include/pcl-1.7 -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/ni -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
CMake Error at KinfuLargeScaleCUDA_generated_colors.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/Jetson/ROS_Workspace/branches/tx1/iruVizhi_v1/build/ros_kinfu/kinfu/pcl_kinfu_large_scale/CMakeFiles/KinfuLargeScaleCUDA.dir/kinfu_large_scale/src/cuda/./KinfuLargeScaleCUDA_generated_colors.cu.o
```

The difference I can make out when comparing the build output from my PC is that the tx1 compile options have some lines with round brackets.  Is that a problem?

```
-DvtkFiltersFlowPaths_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths )
```

May be insignificant, but I also get the below warning on tx1 and not on my pc

```
  Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251156/unable-to-solve-%22nvcc-fatal:-a-single-input-file-is-required-for-a-non-link-phase-when-an-outputfile-is-specified%22--error/) by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-02**:
The parentheses and the whitespace around many of the options looks suspicious. You can try copying the whole line into a shell script and running it to verify that it produces the same error (you may need to add quotes around some things)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-02**:
Once you have a shell script that reproduces the issue, you can try to modify it in various ways until it works. Once you know how to make this one line work, the challenge is simplified to figuring out how to make cmake do the same thing (which is still not that simple :P )

**Comment by [vinmean](https://answers.ros.org/users/27224/vinmean/) on 2017-01-02**:
Thank you. I removed the parentheses from the command and then it executes without any error. So how do I ensure cmake generates a command without these brackets? I see that only the vtk command options seems to have this problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-03**:
I don't know. Perhaps you can read the cmake files for finding Cuda and VTK and see where it gets those options, or do a recursive grep of your filesystem to see which file those options are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try adding this to your CMakeLists.txt:

`set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "" )`

---

Originally posted by [trsaunders](https://answers.ros.org/users/29603/trsaunders/) with karma: 66 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karol Majek](https://answers.ros.org/users/32281/karol-majek/) on 2017-10-17**:
This works perfectly!

**Comment by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) on 2018-01-12**:
To me too! Mark it as the answer :)

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2018-06-11**:
What kind of sorcery is this??  It worked for me too, care to elaborate, please?

**Comment by [trsaunders](https://answers.ros.org/users/29603/trsaunders/) on 2018-06-12**:
From what I can remember there's something in COMPILE_DEFINITONS that's not being escaped properly. Unfortunately I can't remember how I came to this conclusion

**Comment by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) on 2019-05-09**:
Works on my side!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parenthesis that you observed in your compilation calls are definitions for function-like macros, and are valid preprocessor directives for the gcc compiler. However, they are not valid for certain CUDA compilers due the latter's inability to handle these redunant spaces between the characters that you observed.

What is likely happening is that your code uses the Point Cloud Library (PCL), with some necessary variables for it loaded into your CMakeLists.txt through the find_package(PCL) command, which runs PCLConfig.cmake. Since PCL depends on VTK (Visualization Toolkit), PCLConfig.cmake runs UseVTK.cmake. The latter file, due to poor design, adds flags into the CMAKE_C_FLAGS and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS directly (as opposed to adding them to something like VTK_CXX_FLAGS so that the user could use these flags optionally). This has the unintended consequence that the flags are passed to nvcc due to the way FindCUDA.cmake is set up: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake#L1407. Due to the fact that nvcc can't handle function-like macros with spaces around the parenthesis, an error is given.

As a solution, one can clear all the compiler flags (thus getting rid of the redundant function-like macros due to VTK) by using the `set_directory_properties( PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "" )` command in cmake before building cuda with the CUDA_COMPILE cmake macro.

---

Originally posted by [stensootla](https://answers.ros.org/users/39214/stensootla/) with karma: 11 on 2018-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1